# 指定した画像を表示させたい

Tags: html

15行目の画像を表示させたいです。
現在まで、誤字とタグ確認、他サイトでの確認。
ファイルには、課題のファイル-課題名-image-image/logo_green.png
の順でファイルにあります。
また、疑問としてHTMLとjavascrptでそれぞれ使う画像は別にしないと表示できないのでしょうか？

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>株式会社LiNew</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
  <script src=""></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
   <div class="header-box">
     <div id="inner-header">
        <img src="image/logo_green.png">
       <ul class="header-list">
        <li class="header-list">News</li>
        <li class="header-list">About</li>
        <li class="header-list">Serice</li>
        <li class="header-list">Recruit</li>
        <li class="header-list">Contact</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="fadein-header">
      <p> <img src="image/IMG_0224-1.jpeg"></p>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 実現したいこと (=画像を表示させたい) に対して、現状だとどんな問題がありますか？質問はあとからでも編集できるので、より詳しい状況を追記してみてください。

Comment: 初めて使いうので丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: ご参考にさせて頂きます。

Answer (score 1):

- 他の img タグと見比べると、問題の箇所は `src` と `=` の間に余計な空白文字が含まれているのが気になります。
- HTML の記述では HTML ファイルの直下に `image/` フォルダがあり、その下に画像があるはずですが、言葉での說明とは食い違いがあるように見えます。

Comment: 解決いたしました。ありがとうございます。